# Referencing and printing a 2D array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

I've been reading about how you can't have an array of arrays in Perl thus I ended up struggling with references of arrays and I think I figure out how to return the array from a subroutine. However I can't get it to print the entire array after the return. Can someone explain to me why or how to debug this issue? It would be really appreciated indeed!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#Subroutine to randomize the 2D Array:
sub randPattern {
my ($rand_ref) = @_;
my @RandBoard = @$rand_ref;

for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#RandBoard; $i++) {
  for (my $j = 0; $j <= $#RandBoard ; $j++) {
     $RandBoard[$i][$j] = 0 + int(rand(3 - 0));
     print "$RandBoard[$i][$j] ";
   }
   print "\n";
  }

return @RandBoard;
}

my @checkerArr =  (
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
);

my ($randomizedArr_ref) = randPattern(\@checkerArr); #sending arrayy as reference
my @randomizedArr = @$randomizedArr_ref; #dereferencing the returned array
print "___________________\n";

foreach (@randomizedArr){
print "$_ "; }
print "\n";
```

And the output is like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 0 2 1 
1 0 0 0 2 2 0 1 
2 1 1 2 1 2 0 1 
1 2 0 2 0 1 0 1 
1 2 1 2 0 0 1 0 
2 1 0 1 0 0 0 2 
2 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 
___________________
1 1 1 1 1 0 2 1
```

As you can see it only outputs the first row of the array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, let me fix your code, then I'll explain...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#Subroutine to randomize the 2D Array:
sub randPattern {
my ($rand_ref) = $_[0];
my @RandBoard = @$rand_ref;

for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#RandBoard; $i++) {
  for (my $j = 0; $j <= $#{$RandBoard[$i]} ; $j++) {
     $RandBoard[$i][$j] = 0 + int(rand(3 - 0));
     print "$RandBoard[$i][$j] ";
   }
   print "\n";
  }

return @RandBoard;
}

my @checkerArr =  (
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
);

my ($randomizedArr_ref) = [randPattern(\@checkerArr)]; #sending arrayy as reference
my @randomizedArr = @$randomizedArr_ref; #dereferencing the returned array
print "___________________\n";

foreach (@randomizedArr){
    print(join(' ',@$_),"\n");
}
```

The main issue here is scalar context versus list context.  You're returning a list from your subroutine and assigning that returned list in a scalar context ($randomizedArr_ref).  You were getting an array reference (which was actually the *last* element of your outer array.  You need to evaluate the return of the method in list context, so I added the square brackets around your method call (`[randPattern(\@checkerArr)]`).

I also changed `@_` to `$_[0]` to your setting of the parameter in the subroutine, which is a similar oversight.  You were only getting the whlole parameter because you were passing in a single scalar (reference to an array).

Oh, and in your loop, I added a dereference of the array and joined with a space.  I also moved the newline into the loop.

UPDATE: Found another error I overlooked.  The size of the inner array tested in the inner for loop was using the size of the outer array (which happened to be the same).  So I changed the inner for loop to get the size of the inner array with `$#{$RandBoard[$i]}`.

Comment: Also, you can actually simplify it quite a bit.  Some people may object to the usage of map like this for readability, but I tend to err on the side of less code: `print(join("\n",map {join(" ",map {int(rand(3))} 1..8)} 1..8),"\n")`. That's pretty much your whole program right there. You can also initialize an array with 8 0s using `(0)x8`.

Comment: Probably got a down-vote because I missed a few little things, but I've made updates to fix them. Note, I tried to leave most of the code as-is so it wouldn't be overwhelming numbers of changes and the answer would focus on the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've overcomplicated it somewhat.

Perl does do 2D arrays, and you're correct in thinking the the *implementation* of that is via references.

It may be useful to know that `Data::Dumper` is really handy for printing the contents of a complex data structure.

The core of your problem is in how these two iteract:

```
return @RandBoard;
```

this returns multiple values.

But this only 'uses' one of them, and discards the rest:

```
my ($randomizedArr_ref) = randPattern(\@checkerArr);
```

So what you're 'catching' is just the reference to the first line - and then printing it. If you were to try:

```
my ( @results ) = randPattern(\@checkerArr);
```

Then you'd come closer, but I'd suggest simple solution is:

```
return \@RandBoard;
```

Which returns the whole data structure as a reference:

```
foreach my $row ( @$randomizedArr_ref ) {
    print join " ", @$row; 
}
```

Making your code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;


#Subroutine to randomize the 2D Array:
sub randPattern {
   my ($rand_ref) = @_;
   my @RandBoard = @$rand_ref;

   for ( my $i = 0; $i <= $#RandBoard; $i++ ) {
      for ( my $j = 0; $j <= $#RandBoard; $j++ ) {
         $RandBoard[$i][$j] = 0 + int( rand( 3 - 0 ) );
         print "$RandBoard[$i][$j] ";
      }
      print "\n";
   }

   return \@RandBoard;
}

my @checkerArr = (
   [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
   [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
   [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
   [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
   [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
   [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
   [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
   [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
);

my ($randomizedArr_ref) =
  randPattern( \@checkerArr );    #sending arrayy as reference


print "____\n";
foreach my $row (@$randomizedArr_ref) {
   print join " ", @$row, "\n";
}
```

But actually you could simplify your code massively:

```
foreach my $row ( @checkerArr ) { 
    $_ = int rand(3) for @$row; 
}
```

Or just:

```
my @checkerArr = map { 
                        [ 
                            map { int rand(3) } (1..8) #array of 8 random values
                        ] 
                     } (1..8); #8 rows.
```

Comment: You left the error in the inner for loop where he loops over the size of the outer array `$#RandBoard`.